# InvokeRequired doubt

Tags: c#, invokerequired

The following method will be invoked from a non UI thread. Should I check InvokeRequired, for calling these items in the method?

a. this._moduleStatusGrid.Invalidate()
b. this.Close()

```
private void CheckIfAllModulesInitComplete()
      {
        this._moduleStatusGrid.Invalidate();
        if (this._moduleDataList.Count(moduleData => !moduleData.IsInitOver) == 0)
        {
          this._footprint.DeActivate();
          this.Close();
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

Control.Invoke and Control.BeginInvoke are safe to call from the UI thread and non-UI threads, so if you already know you are on a non-UI thread there is no harm (IMO) skipping the check and just calling Invoke/BeginInvoke.

Example:

```
anyControl.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate{
    // anything to run on UI thread here
});
```

Comment: This saved me a ton of refactoring on a problem I've been pulling my hair out over for a couple of days.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could be asking one of the following

1. Given that this method runs in a background thread, within the methods `Invalidate` and `Close` should I be checking the `InvokeRequired` property?
2. Given that this method runs in a background thread the `InvokeRequired` property will always return `false` so should I just avoid checking it?

For #1 the answer is no.  The methods `Close` and `Invalidate` don't have a responsibility to check the `InvokeRequired` property.  It is an implicit part of their contract that the `InvokeRequired` property be false before they are called.

For #2, yes if it's always called on a background thread I would skip the check and just go straight to the `Invoke` methods.

In either case I would rewrite the method as follows.

```
private void CheckIfAllModulesInitComplete()
{
  MethodInvoker del = delegate {
    this._moduleStatusGrid.Invalidate();
    if (this._moduleDataList.Count(moduleData => !moduleData.IsInitOver) == 0)
    {
      this._footprint.DeActivate();
      this.Close();
    }
  };
  this.Invoke(del, null);
}
```

Comment: @JaredPar- Thanks.. Just to know - What would happen if this._moduleStatusGrid.Invalidate() or this.Close() is called direcly from the callback thread?

Comment: @Maanu, bad things. Occasionally, in some .Net versions, the app will continue running with no apparent issue.  But it doesn't mean the operation is any safer.  Calling these methods from a BG thread is simply dangerous and will cause issues down the road